The wedge product of two positive forms is positive
I have previously posted this question on MSE, but still didn't solve it.

Definition. A real $(p, p)$-form $\psi$ on a complex manifold $M^{n}$ is said to be (semi-) positive, if for any $x \in M$, and any linearly independent $(1,0)$-type tangent vectors $X_{1}, \cdots, X_{p}$ at $x$, it holds
$$(-\sqrt{-1})^{p^{2}} \psi\left(X_{1}, \cdots, X_{p}, \overline{X_{1}}, \cdots, \overline{X_{p}}\right)>0~(\text{or}\geq0)$$
We will denote this by $\psi>0$ (or $\geq 0$).



Exercise 1. For any $(p, 0)$-form $\varphi$, $(\sqrt{-1})^{p^{2}} \varphi \wedge \bar{\varphi} \geq 0$.
Exercise 2. Locally, if we take a frame $\left\{\varphi_{1}, \cdots, \varphi_{n}\right\}$ of $(1,0)$-forms, then any $(p, p)$-form $\psi$ can be expressed as
$$\psi=(\sqrt{-1})^{p^{2}} \sum f_{I \bar{J}} \varphi_{I} \wedge \overline{\varphi_{J}}$$
where $\varphi_{I}=\varphi_{i_{1}} \wedge \cdots \wedge \varphi_{i_{p}}$ if $I=\left\{i_{1}< \cdots< i_{p}\right\}$ and $J=\left\{j_{1}< \cdots< j_{p}\right\}$, and the sum runs through all the multiindices $I,J \subset\{1, \ldots, n\}$ with $|I|=|J|=p$. Denote by $F=\left(f_{I \bar{J}}\right)$ the square matrix ($C_n^p\times C_n^p$ matrix). Then $\psi$ is real if and only if $F$ is a Hermitian matrix, and $\psi>0$ (or $\geq 0$) if and only if $F$ is (semi-) positive definite everywhere.
Exercise 3. From the description of exercise 2, show that if $\psi_{1}$ is a positive $(p, p)$-form and $\psi_{2}$ is a positive $(q, q)$-form, then when $p+q\leq n, \psi_{1} \wedge \psi_{2}>0$.

Exercise 1 and 2 are both easy:
$$(-\sqrt{-1})^{p^{2}} (\sqrt{-1})^{p^{2}} \varphi \wedge \bar{\varphi}\left(X_{1}, \cdots, X_{p}, \overline{X_{1}}, \cdots, \overline{X_{p}}\right)$$
$$=\varphi\left(X_{1}, \cdots, X_{p}\right)\cdot\bar{\varphi}\left(\overline{X_{1}}, \cdots, \overline{X_{p}}\right)=\left|\varphi\left(X_{1}, \cdots, X_{p}\right)\right|^2\geq0.$$
So $(\sqrt{-1})^{p^{2}} \varphi \wedge \bar{\varphi} \geq 0$. And
\begin{align*}
&\quad\sum f_{I \bar{J}} \varphi_{I} \wedge \overline{\varphi_{J}}\left(X_{1}, \cdots, X_{p}, \overline{X_{1}}, \cdots, \overline{X_{p}}\right)\\
&=\sum f_{I \bar{J}} \varphi_{I}\left(X_{1}, \cdots, X_{p}\right) \overline{\varphi_{J}}\left( \overline{X_{1}}, \cdots, \overline{X_{p}}\right)\\
&=\sum f_{I \bar{J}} \det\left(\varphi_{i_\alpha}(X_\beta)\right)_{\alpha\beta} \cdot\overline{\det\left(\varphi_{j_\alpha}(X_\beta)\right)_{\alpha\beta}}\\
&=\sum f_{I \bar{J}} \det\left(X_\beta^{i_\alpha}\right)_{\alpha\beta} \cdot\overline{\det\left(X_\beta^{j_\alpha}\right)_{\alpha\beta}}.
\end{align*}
So
$$\psi>0\Leftrightarrow\sum f_{I \bar{J}} \det\left(X_\beta^{i_\alpha}\right)_{\alpha\beta} \cdot\overline{\det\left(X_\beta^{j_\alpha}\right)_{\alpha\beta}}>0\Leftrightarrow\left(f_{I \bar{J}}\right){\rm is~positive~definite}.$$

For exercise 3, write
$$\psi_1=(\sqrt{-1})^{p^{2}} \sum f_{I \bar{J}} \varphi_{I} \wedge \overline{\varphi_{J}}\quad{\rm and}\quad\psi_2=(\sqrt{-1})^{q^{2}} \sum g_{K \bar{L}} \varphi_{K} \wedge \overline{\varphi_{L}},$$
then
\begin{align*}
\psi_1\wedge\psi_2&=(\sqrt{-1})^{p^{2}+q^{2}}\sum_{I,J,K,L}f_{I \bar{J}}g_{K \bar{L}} \varphi_{I} \wedge \overline{\varphi_{J}}\wedge\varphi_{K} \wedge \overline{\varphi_{L}}\\
&=(\sqrt{-1})^{(p+q)^{2}}\sum_{I,J,K,L}f_{I \bar{J}}g_{K \bar{L}} \varphi_{I}\wedge\varphi_{K}  \wedge \overline{\varphi_{J}}\wedge \overline{\varphi_{L}}.
\end{align*}
But note that the sub-scripts of $\varphi_{I}\wedge\varphi_{K}$ may not be arranged in ascending order. If we arrange these sub-scripts from small to large, then what's the matrix?

I have done it for the wedge product of two positive $(1,1)$-forms:
Firstly, fix $k\in\{1,\cdots,n\}$ consider $\psi_1=\sqrt{-1}\varphi_k\wedge\bar\varphi_k$ and $\psi_2=\sqrt{-1}\sum_{i,j}g_{i\bar j} \varphi_i\wedge\bar\varphi_j>0$, where $(g_{i\bar j})$ is positive definite. Then
$$\psi_1\wedge\psi_2=(\sqrt{-1})^{2^2}\sum_{i,j}g_{i\bar j}\varphi_k\wedge\varphi_i\wedge\bar\varphi_k\wedge\bar\varphi_j.$$
Denote by $P$ the following matrix
$$\left(\begin{matrix}
g_{11} & \cdots & g_{1,k-1} & -g_{1,k+1} & \cdots & -g_{1n} \\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
g_{k-1,1} & \cdots & g_{k-1,k-1} & -g_{k-1,k+1} & \cdots & -g_{k-1,n} \\
-g_{k+1,1} & \cdots & -g_{k+1,k-1} & g_{k+1,k+1} & \cdots & g_{k+1,n} \\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
-g_{n1} & \cdots & -g_{n,k-1} & g_{n,k+1} & \cdots & g_{nn}
\end{matrix}\right),$$
then the matrix of $\psi_1\wedge\psi_2$ is $\left(\begin{matrix}
P & O \\
O & O
\end{matrix}\right)$, up to a congruence transformation consisting of some elementary transformations. It's well-known that
$$\left|\begin{matrix}
A & B \\
C & D
\end{matrix}\right|=|A|~|D-CA^{-1}B|=\left|\begin{matrix}
A & -B \\
-C & D
\end{matrix}\right|.$$
Therefore $P$ is positive definite, and $\left(\begin{matrix}
P & O \\
O & O
\end{matrix}\right)$ is semi-positive definite.
Now consider $\psi_1=\sum_k\sqrt{-1}\varphi_k\wedge\bar\varphi_k>0$ and $\psi_2=\sqrt{-1}\sum_{i,j}g_{i\bar j} \varphi_i\wedge\bar\varphi_j>0$. Its matrix is the sum of matrices of the form
$$\left(\begin{matrix}
O & O & O & O & O \\
O & A & O & B & O \\
O & O & O & O & O \\
O & B^T & O & C & O \\
O & O & O & O & O \\
\end{matrix}\right)$$
(possibly the non-zero entries are more scattered), where $\left(\begin{matrix}
A & B \\
B^T & C
\end{matrix}\right)$ is positive definite. By the definition of positive definite matrix, we have $\psi_1\wedge\psi_2>0$. WLOG, $\psi_1$ is an arbitrary positive $(1,1)$-form. This proves the case of the wedge product of two positive $(1,1)$-forms.
For a general $(p,p)$-form $\psi$, I am not sure if it can be represented as $\psi=\sum_I\varphi_I\wedge\bar\varphi_I$ without loss of generality.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

I haven't read your entire solution, but it seems to me that you need a lemma that any nonnegative $(p, p)$ form is a sum of $\phi_I \wedge \bar{\phi}_I$. This is a bit similar to the statement that any hermitian posiitive semidefinite matrix has nonnegative eigenvalues, and probably follows from it using multilinear algebra magic...


What is your question? 2. Are you aware of this paper? https://www.math.stonybrook.edu/~aknapp/pdf-files/reese-harvey.pdf


See also http://www.numdam.org/articles/10.1016/j.crma.2013.01.009/ and http://www2.im.uj.edu.pl/phd/DinewPhd2009_eng.pdf

What is $J$ in the sum over $I$ in Exercise 2?

@Malkoun Yes, I have found the lemma you pointed out in YangMills' comment.

@YangMills Thank you for including these references. Harvey and Knapp's paper is very useful.

@LSpice The sum runs over all $I$ and $J$ with $|J|=p$. I will edit this typo.

Just a comment/question, is the exponent really $p^2$, or maybe just $p$? For example, $dx \wedge dy = \frac{i}{2} dz \wedge d\bar{z}$.

@Malkoun It's $p^2$ indeed. If it's $p$, then the definition should be$$(-\sqrt{-1})^p \psi\left(X_{1}, \overline{X_{1}}, \cdots, X_{p}, \overline{X_{p}}\right)>0~(\text{or}\geq0).$$This definition can be found on page 170 of Zheng's Complex Differential Geometry and page 220 of Lee's Introduction to Complex Manifolds.

In Harvey-Knapp you will also find a counterexample to the statement that the wedge product of two positive forms is positive (see also the other references I linked). Does this answer your question (which, honestly, I still don't know what it is)?

@YangMills Yes, Harvey-Knapp answers my question. My main question is that I cannot prove the wedge product of two positive forms is positive, or more precisely, the details encountered in my solution to it. The counterexample you pointed out is about weakly positive defined in Harvey-Knapp.

Just take the example of Harvey-Knapp (or those in the references above) and add to their weakly positive $(p,p)$ forms $\varepsilon\omega^p$ where $\omega$ is the standard Euclidean Kahler form, and $\varepsilon>0$ is sufficiently small.
